# Antlr parsing rule to parse string with matching braces

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a parser rule which looks like below

```
nested_query: ~(LPARAN | RPARAN)+? LPARAN nested_query RPARAN ~(LPARAN | RPARAN)+?
    | nested_query nested_query_op LPARAN nested_query RPARAN
    | ~(LPARAN | RPARAN)+?
    ;
nested_query_op: binary_in | binary_not_in ;
binary_in: 'in'; 
binary_not_in: 'not' 'in';
LPARAN: '(';
RPARAN: ')';
```

This correctly matches the string `list(srcVm) of flows where typeTag ="TAG_SRC_IP_VM" until timestamp`

[image]

But when I try to parse a string having more than one matching brackets it does not get properly parsed for example `list(srcVm) of flows where (typeTag ="TAG_SRC_IP_VM") until timestamp`

[image]

Can someone let me know how can I modify the above rule to match a string with more than one matching braces under `nested_query` rule like below

```
                      nested_query:1
                            |
    ---------------------------------------------------------         
    list ( nested_query:3 ) of flows where ( nested_query:4) until timestamp                                                   
                  |                                |
                srcVM                    (typeTag ="TAG_SRC_IP_VM")
```

Comment: Can you specify more info please. What are the definitions of LPARAN/RPARAN/nested_query_op/... ?

Comment: Updated the question. I missed those rules. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
nested_query
 : ( LPARAN nested_query RPARAN | ~( LPARAN | RPARAN ) )+
 ;
```

`list(srcVm) of flows where typeTag ="TAG_SRC_IP_VM" until timestamp`

[image]

`list(srcVm) of flows where (typeTag ="TAG_SRC_IP_VM") until timestamp`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well there simply isn't any rule that would allow input with two sets of parentheses following each other *without `in`|`not in` just in front of the second opening brace`*:

- The only first alternative in `nested_query` only allows one occurrence of parentheses (although they might be nested) - outside of the top-level parentheses the must be no parentheses.
- The second alternative allows top-level parentheses (from first `nested_query`) followed by non-parentheses, then `in` or `not in` and then second top/level parentheses.
- The third alternative doesn't allow parentheses at all.

To match multiple parentheses on one level, the first alternative of `nested_query` should be something like

```
~(LPARAN | RPARAN)* (LPARAN nested_query RPARAN ~(LPARAN | RPARAN)*)+ ~(LPARAN | RPARAN)*
```

But then the second alternative will be in conflict with this, because everything that can match it can also match this modified first alternative.

Comment: Is there a way I can modify the `nested_query` parsing rule to match `list(srcVm) of flows where (typeTag ="TAG_SRC_IP_VM") until timestamp` ?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you want to do - you haven't provided much info about that. Do you only want to pair the braces? Do you want to check some other syntax?